# Error import views in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I do not understand why this line fails:  **from library import views**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from library import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

but this does not:  **from library.views import IndexView**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from library.views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

file views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

Comment: Should not it be `views.IndexView.as_view()` in your first example?

Comment: What is the full text of the error?

Comment: @alecxe Yes, you are right

Comment: @FranciscoGarcía reading the full error message *carefully* would have told you which line the error was on, and what the exact error was. The line `from library import views` **did not** fail, it was the definition of `urlpattern[0]` that did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the main class itself not the parent.

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from library import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()), ## this will not work
        url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view()), ## OK
    ]
```

---

In the other scenario

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from library.views import IndexView

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()), ## OK
    ]
```